# How can I add an element to an existing object in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

jQuery code:

```
var addproperty = {
    OwnerName: OwnerName,
    OwnerEmail: OwnerEmail,
    OwnerMobile: OwnerMobile,
    OwnerType: OwnerType,
    Propertyfor: Propertyfor,
    ProjectName: ProjectName,
    ProjectAddress: ProjectAddress,
    State: State,
    City: City,
    Area: Area,
    ProjectType: ProjectType,
    BHK: BHK,
    Bathroom: Bathroom,
    Balcony: Balcony,
    Builtup: Builtup,
    Carpet: Carpet,
    Unit: Unit,
    Furnish: Furnish
}

if(Propertyfor == 'rent'){
    $(addproperty).extend({
        RentPossessionDate: RentPossessionDate,
        MonthlyRent: MonthlyRent,
        Maintanace: Maintanace,
        SecuiryDeposit: SecuiryDeposit,
        Bachelors: Bachelors,
        RentNegotiable: RentNegotiable
});
```

It is not inserting new element into the existing object with `addproperty`. Where is my coding mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're providing the `addproperty` object to the constructor of a jQuery object.

To use `extend()` properly, just use call it from the jQuery object directly, ie `$.extend(obj, newObj)`, like this:

```js
var addproperty = {
  OwnerName: 'OwnerName',
  OwnerEmail: 'OwnerEmail',
  OwnerMobile: 'OwnerMobile',
  OwnerType: 'OwnerType',
  Propertyfor: 'Propertyfor',
  ProjectName: 'ProjectName',
  ProjectAddress: 'ProjectAddress',
  State: 'State',
  City: 'City',
  Area: 'Area',
  ProjectType: 'ProjectType',
  BHK: 'BHK',
  Bathroom: 'Bathroom',
  Balcony: 'Balcony',
  Builtup: 'Builtup',
  Carpet: 'Carpet',
  Unit: 'Unit',
  Furnish: 'Furnish'
}

var Propertyfor = 'rent';

if (Propertyfor == 'rent') {
  $.extend(addproperty, {
    RentPossessionDate: 'RentPossessionDate',
    MonthlyRent: 'MonthlyRent',
    Maintanace: 'Maintanace',
    SecuiryDeposit: 'SecuiryDeposit',
    Bachelors: 'Bachelors',
    RentNegotiable: 'RentNegotiable'
  });
}

console.log(addproperty);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that for the above to work I had to change the property values to strings as you did not provide that part of your codebase.

Comment: No problem bro for string conversion but now it working I will accept your answer within 6 minutes

Answer (score 0):

I fixed some issues in your code. There were many spelling mistakes. The `extend` function has to be supplied with the object you want to extend and also the a new object containing the properties you need.

```
var addProperty = {
    OwnerName: 'OwnerName',
    OwnerEmail: 'OwnerEmail',
    OwnerMobile: 'OwnerMobile',
    OwnerType: 'OwnerType',
    Propertyfor: 'rent',
    ProjectName: 'ProjectName',
    ProjectAddress: 'ProjectAddress',
    State: 'State',
    City: 'City',
    Area: 'Area',
    ProjectType: 'ProjectType',
    BHK: 'BHK',
    Bathroom: 'Bathroom',
    Balcony: 'Balcony',
    Builtup: 'Builtup',
    Carpet: 'Carpet',
    Unit: 'Unit',
    Furnish: 'Furnish'
};

if (addProperty.Propertyfor == 'rent') {
    var obj = { RentPossessionDate: 'RentPossessionDate',
                MonthlyRent: 'MonthlyRent',
                Maintanace: 'Maintanace',
                SecuiryDeposit: 'SecuiryDeposit',
                Bachelors: 'Bachelors',
                RentNegotiable: 'RentNegotiable'
              };
    $.extend(addProperty, obj);
    console.log(addProperty);
}
```

Observe the console. Here's a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fqtaoo6s/